# How can we make physical memory pages uncacheable in armv7 (probably by modifying page table entry)?

Tags: linux, arm, kernel, mmu

I need to make physical memory pages uncacheable, it seems that in armv7 (I am using arm cortex A9) there are some bits that determine the memory type. we have two level translations (so we have `pgd` and `pte` and we do not use `pmd` and pud). Based on the manual, bit C, B, and TEX of the second level translation table entry (which I considered it as `pte` in the kernel code) determine whether the memory page is cacheable or not, therefore by changing them, we can change cache ability.

what I think I found useful is, `pgprot_noncached()` which I gave one specific virtual memory's `"vma->vm_page_prot"` as its argument, I did not see any changes in `"pte"` that I printed.

I am wondering I might need to use `set_pte_ext()` to set changes of memory type of that specific virtual memory area in page table entry (`pte`)?

Want to know I am assuming all of these correctly or anyone has a similar experience?

Comment: yes as shown in the arm documentation you can make a page cached or not cached.

Comment: @old_timer, thanks. My problem is more about implementation and kernel APIs that I need to use, I just used "pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot)" but didn't see any changes in content of pte.

Comment: improving format and fixing the grammar.